# design database tables for school fees collectin system

Tags: java, mysql

I needed a help in designing database tables for a school fees collection system in java and mysql , I did extensive research but could not find a solution.

- There are three terms (trimester) in an academic year
- Students pay the fees at the start of every term, i.e the fees is collected on termly basis
- The school administration sets the fees for each term depending on the class or form or grade of the student
- Students who use the school bus are charged more than the others, so the transport  fee is different from the tuition fee.
- A student can pay as many times as possible in a specific term, he/she can proceed to the next term without clearing the fees for the previous term.
- When the school set the fees for that particular term, list of the students who did not pay for that term can be displayed

The tables created should be able to give me the following results:

1. List of students with negative balance
2. Termly income
3. Yearly income
4. Payment history for specific student searched

Anyone with an idea...I would really appreciate

Comment: This looks like a homework dump.  Did your "extensive research" include reading your textbook, or asking the instructor for help?

Comment: @ajb I posted a few links in my answer to a few tutorials on the matter.

I think that'll get him started without him just getting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

OK well you're going to need 3 classes minimum:

A `DataBase` Connect Class to connect to your SQL Database to download the data; a `Student` class which contains the 4 things listed above, and a `GUI` class to actually present the data. (It can also be done using simple TableView, but if you're given the opportunity to learn something like JavaFX or Scene Builder then go for it, it'll make it a lot prettier.)

I've linked two websites that do a project very similar to this and take you step by step. You just need to read and manipulate to fit your specifications.

[Scene Builder Tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/)

[MySQL and Java Tutorial](http://365programperday.blogspot.com/2013/07/javafx-and-mysql-sample-illustration.html)

These two things will be more than enough to get you started.

Good luck!

Come back with any specific questions!

Comment: i needed how i should relate database tables

Comment: I don't really understand.

I assume this needs to be done in Java, so you first need to download the databases from MySQL, and then all the actual work is done in Java, or should this all be done in MySQL?

Comment: No, I think the OP needs help with designing the database structure itself...but I could be wrong

Comment: yeah exactly @MadProgrammer  the database structure is what i needed
the java will be used in displaying the results

Comment: OK.

My links still apply.

What you need to do is break this assignment up into two separate components: a SQL part where you build the database, and then you have to download it with Java and make a GUI.